# Data-driven flag setting in derived class constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-driven

Say I have a base class with a flag inside of it which derived classes have to set:

```
struct Base
{
    bool flag;
    Base(bool flag):flag(flag) {}
};
```

I want to configure which derived classes set the flag to `true`/`false` in a data-driven way - i.e. I'd like to configure this from a header.

```
struct Derived1 : Base
{
    Derived1() : Base( expr ) {}
};
```

Where `expr` is *something* (don't know what yet) that is able to get the info from the header - tell whether `Derived1` should make `flag` true or false. Ideally, I'd get an error if I make a new derived class but fail to specify the flag in the header, but this isn't mandatory. This way I can just modify a single central location to make changes.

What's the idiomatic approach for this?

Comment: Why wouldn't a constant template parameter work?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I guess _maaaayybe_ if you have the field declared on the derived and initialize it `constexpr`, you could read it with a trait emplying `declval<T>()` - this is an extremely long shot though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative version that uses a single function might be more compact:

```
struct Derived1 : Base
{
    Derived1() : Base(theFlag(this)) {}
};
```

Then in the header:

```
template <typename T>
bool theFlag(T*)
{
   if (typeid(T) == typeid(Derived1)) return true;
   if (typeid(T) == typeid(Derived2)) return false;
   if (typeid(T) == typeid(Derived3)) return true;

   throw std::runtime_error("No theFlag is given for this type");
}
```

If you are married to the compile-time check, the best you could do is to introduce a bit of duplication:

```
template <typename T>
bool theFlag(T*)
{
   static_assert(
      std::is_same<T, Derived1>::value ||
      std::is_same<T, Derived2>::value ||
      std::is_same<T, Derived3>::value,
      "No theFlag is given for this type"
   );

   if (typeid(T) == typeid(Derived1)) return true;
   if (typeid(T) == typeid(Derived2)) return false;
   if (typeid(T) == typeid(Derived3)) return true;
}
```

This basically relies on SFINAE - the compiler would not be able to find an overload for `theFlag` if you called it with an unsupported argument, essentially.

Comment: Hmmmm, this one looks nicer, yes.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the `static_assert` is right. That is, I'm sure it's not. Perhaps someone can help me correct it before my initial 5 mins are up? :P

Comment: It's completely wrong. Either you perform the type dispatching at compiletime via template specialization, in which case you can static_assert, or the assert will always fail.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yep -- I don't think that I can improve this any further without ending up back at the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

```
struct Derived1 : Base
{
    Derived1() : Base(Concept<Derived1>::theFlag) {}
};
```

And your header could have the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct Concept
{};

template <>
struct Concept<Derived1>
{
   static const bool theFlag = true;
};
```

with the specialisation repeated for each type.

Is that what you meant? Compilation will fail when you didn't give a flag value for some `DerivedN`.

Comment: Perhaps it's a runtime parameter?

Comment: @Gearoid: The contents of headers cannot be decided at runtime.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy no. It's compile-time. @ Lightness yes, similar to this, but I'd like a more compact version.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I'm not sure that I can beat this. C++ doesn't have any sort of native data interchange format.

Comment: Could the same effect be achieved by an enumerated constant?

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: I don't see how if we want to use the type directly.

Comment: you can remove Concept's default definition

Comment: If you do that, you can't use it for SFINAE.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You could use a macro to define specializations, then it's reasonably compact:  https://ideone.com/tEldkC

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Done that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a trait class for flags and use a macro to define specializations:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct FlagTrait {
    static_assert(std::is_void<T>::value, "No flag defined for this type.");
};

#define DEFINE_FLAG(Type, Val)               \
        template<>                           \
        struct FlagTrait<class Type>         \
            : std::integral_constant<bool, Val> {};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool getFlag(T) { return FlagTrait<T>::value; }

#define GET_FLAG getFlag(*this)
```

Now all we need to do for each new derived class is to add a line with class name and value of the flag:

```
DEFINE_FLAG(Derived1, true)
DEFINE_FLAG(Derived2, false)
```

Usage:

```
struct Base
{
    bool flag;
    Base(bool flag):flag(flag) {}
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
    Derived1() : Base(GET_FLAG) {}
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
     Derived2() : Base(GET_FLAG) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure compile-time solution:

```
struct Derived1 ;
struct Derived2 ;
template <typename Derived> struct Bootstrap
{
    bool init(Derived1 *) { return true ; }
    bool init(Derived2 *) { return false ; }
    Bootstrap():flag(init(static_cast<Derived *>(this))){}
    bool flag ;
};
struct Derived1: public Bootstrap <Derived1> {};
struct Derived2: public Bootstrap <Derived2> {};
int main()
{
    Derived1 d1 ;
    Derived2 d2 ;
    std::cout<<d1.flag<<" "<<d2.flag<<std::endl ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by 'Lightness Races in Orbit', static_cast during ctor process can cause Undefined Behabiour (UB). Here's an updated implementation which negates the need for the static_cast operator:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Derived1 ;
struct Derived2 ;
namespace BootstrapDetail
{
    template <typename Identifier> bool init();
    template <> bool init <Derived1>() { return true ; }
    template <> bool init <Derived2>() { return false ; }
}
template <typename Derived> struct Bootstrap
{
    Bootstrap(): flag(BootstrapDetail::init<Derived>()) {}
    bool flag ;
};
struct Derived1: public Bootstrap <Derived1> {};
struct Derived2: public Bootstrap <Derived2> {};
int main()
{
    Derived1 d1 ;
    Derived2 d2 ;
    std::cout<<d1.flag<<" "<<d2.flag<<std::endl ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `struct Derived1*` and `struct Derived2*` *cough*

Comment: Does that convention need to be followed in C++?

Comment: No, but it keeps the code shorter. :) It's effectively an inline declaration, meaning you don't need the `struct Derived1;` and `struct Derived2;` at the top anymore.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know that. Does it work for 'class' structures too?

Comment: Is `static_cast<Derived *>(this)` valid in a base ctor-initialiser?

Comment: I believe so, asfaik only dynamic_cast operations are subject to ctor restrictions.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: No some static casts are restricted during initialisation too (see 12.7/3, for example). Though I can't find any wording to prohibit your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687396/is-it-legal-to-cast-this-to-derived-in-the-base-ctor-initialiser

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, good point (good question too), I guess since the pointer is not dereferenced the potential for undefined behaviour is eliminated or at least reduced.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: Arguably just _having_ the casted pointer is already UB :)